# Chart not showing data correctly

Tags: c#, database, charts, series

I have a really weird problem with MS Chart control. What I want to do, is to show several data values over time, but I'm getting some really weird results...

For example: I have a database (Access) which contains tables something like this:

- USERS (ID, Name,...)
- RECEIPTS (ID, ReceiptNumber, Amount, DateOfReceipt, RecipientID, UserID)
- RECIPIENTS (ID, RecipientName)

I want to display (preferably on LINE Chart) amounts spend with each recipient (i.e.: Recipient would be like SevenEleven, Elector, McDonald's, etc...), so the X axis would represent "Date" part of the receipt, Y axis would be the value (amount), an the LINE would obviously represent the recipient. So, if there are 60 receipts for.ex. seven different recipients and with their dates respectively, how would I go about it?

I've tried pulling data into datatable with this SQL

```
SELECT 
    Recipients.Recipient, SUM(Receipts.Amount) AS Skupaj, DateOf 
FROM 
    Receipts 
LEFT JOIN 
    Recipients ON Recipients.ID = Receipts.Recipient 
WHERE 
    Receipts.Recipient = 1 
GROUP BY 
    Recipients.Recipient, Receipts.Amount;
```

but it got all messed up... Then I tried looping thru datatable and creating new series for each recipient - no avail

```
Series series;

string legendData = "";

for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // get data for legend
    legendData = datatable.Rows [i].Field<string>(0) + ": " + datatable.Rows [i].Field<decimal>(1).ToString();

    series = new Series
             {
                // set legend value
                LegendText = legendData, //datatable.Rows [i].Field<string>(0) + " " + datatable.Rows [i].Field<decimal>(2).ToString(),
                                         // set X axis data
                XValueMember = "DateOf",
                // set Y axis data
                YValueMembers = "Skupaj",
                // set chart type
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line,
                // set a bit of colors for data charting
                Palette = ChartColorPalette.Excel,
                // is the value of data printed on chart line
                IsValueShownAsLabel = false,
                // is data visible in the legend
                IsVisibleInLegend = true,
             };

 chartData.Series.Add(series);
```

But to no avail...

Also the Name of the Recipient should appear in the legend, but it doesn't, so I had to add it manually. Hence this line:

```
legendData = datatable.Rows [i].Field<string>(0) + ": " + datatable.Rows [i].Field<decimal>(1).ToString();
```

The data shown in the chart is so messed up that it looks like it was made by Picasso...

I guess I'm doing something wrong or even have the whole thing approached from the wrong angle...

Does anyone have a clue what am I doing wrong, or (even better!) provide a sample for me (and others, I'm sure) to look at and try it for my self?

Regards and best wishes! #stayHome & #beHealthy

NEW DATA ON POST:

[This is Column chart type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyJ55.png)

[And this is spline chart type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biMy5.png)

Note The highlighted data above the chart - they should be summarized. Also note the X axis - it's monthly spaced...

And this is the actual SQL string for this series of data:

```
public static string TEST_BY_PREJEMNIKI =
                        "SELECT DISTINCT Recipients.Recipient, " +
                        "SUM(Receipts.Amount) AS Amount, Receipts.DateOf " +
                        "FROM Receipts LEFT JOIN Recipients ON Recipients.ID = " +
                        "Receipts.Recipient GROUP BY Recipients.Recipient, Receipts.Amount, Receipts.DateOf ORDER BY Receipts.DateOf;";
```

And the code part of it...

```
            adapter.Fill(datatable);
        chartData.DataSource = datatable;
        connection.Close();

        #endregion DATABASE STUFF

        #region PLOTTING CHART DATA

        chartData.Series [0].XValueMember = "DateOf";
        chartData.Series [0].YValueMembers = "Amount";
        chartData.Series [0].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
        chartData.Series [0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        chartData.Series [0].Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
```

Comment: `XValueMember = "DateOf"` is that of type DateTime? Do you eeally want 7 lines of different colors for the recipients ? How does the DataTable look? ok?

Comment: That is correct! It is of type DateTime. Actually what I want is that each line represents one recipient (ie Supplier). If I connect the same DataTable to DataGridView, the output also doesn't look right. So I imagined that the problem lied in my SQL query... I've tried 1001 different queries (buld by hand, buld by MS Access, ...) but to no avail. Each and every time something went wrong. I've even tested the darn thing in Access itself (used query builder and charting report) and lo-and-behold: it worked like a charm! So I went and copied SQL string to my code - No GO! Just didn't work...

Comment: About those seven colors... Maybe I really do not understand, how the char control works in the first place, but I imagined that I have to create separate series for each Recipient... I don't know... If you can imagine the scenario: We have 10 suppliers, each of them is connected to different number of invoices. Each invoice has own Date and Amount. So therefore I want to show (on one chart area) lines representing each amount over time (for ex: Sup1 has 10 invoices over 3 month, Sup2 has 6 and so on) So each point is the amount of the invoice (connected by line) to represent supplier.

Comment: Well the idea to have one series per recipient will work fine, as long as there are not too many of them. - The real issue surely is with the data.

Comment: Well, I guess there will not be much of them (the App is for personal use - like personal ledger, so there are just so many stores around...). And yes, I concure that the problem lies with data somewhere... BUT where? Do you have any suggestions about getting this "thing" done? I really don't care if they are plotted on a single series as long as they are plotted right and are represented in the legend respectively... Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any of the data, the wrong, the right data, the wrong or the expected output. - I haven't touched access in a long time; maybe its has some tricks with its sql building..?

Comment: HI! As I can't add pictures to post-reply, I edited the original post. So please look upwards for detail...

Comment: Can't say I see an image. Also: The Select is missing a sort by date clause, which is needed for a line graph (as opposed to say a column chart) or else the line connections will jump around..

Comment: There are links to images above the SQL section... (took me awhile to see that too...). By sort by Date, are you referring to this: "ORDER BY Receipts.DateOf" ?

Comment: Ah, yes. Best format post to avoid any horizontal scollbars.. Splines/Curves tend to produce artifacts when they change direction to sharply. Change to Lines, which will also avoid the impression of actually having the in-between values.

Comment: Thanks! But there's still a problem of not showing data correctly... First off: The X axis shold NOT be devided monthly, but by actual dates  (data comming from datatable), second: If there is more than one receipt (Expence that is) on the same day by the same Supplier (for. ex.: someone want to the same store twice in the same day - hence got two receipts), those values should be added up and shown as one point in a day...

Comment: To encapsulate: all expences should be represented  "by actual date", wich is not the case in my problem, as the X axis is somehow weirdly formatted. Also (as part of testing stuff) I've requested it to plot just two receipts from the same supplier (for.ex.: one on date 12/6 and other on 8/9). What happened was the columns were sized over time span like a week or so.. One started on 8/6 and spanned over to 15/6... No logic whatsoever...  I guess I've just over complicated darn thing and messed thigs up so badly that would probably be better to start oll over again...

Comment: Hehe. _messed thigs up so badly that would probably be better to start oll over again_ Sounds quite familiar ;-) - The X-Axis Intervals always are equal; the points should be spaced proportionally but the gridlines are always at equal distances. - _twice in the same day - hence got two receipts), those values should be added up and shown as one point in a day_ This should be done by preparing the data before creating the chart.

Comment: Yea...! Thanks much! I guess I'll give it a go and re-think it all over. Maybe even reevaluate my database schema and the concept... Thanks again! See ya!